# Padding size set to 100%, but covers half of the page?

Tags: css

I have styled a div so that I can have a bar at the top of the page for site navigation. Everything goes fine, but the padding of the bar refuses to cover the whole page? When I reload the page, I can see the bar flickering to cover the whole page, but it is then re-sized to about 50% of my browser.

This is my code:

```
div.title_main
{
    background-color:rgb(40,40,40);
    position:fixed;
    right:50%;
    top:-1%;
    padding:0.1% 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your intended result?

Comment: Probably because your positioning it 50% from the right side of the screen? If you remove that `right:50%` doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `right: 50%;` then it should work.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfNyq/1/)